# Whenever I try to enter something in an input, it just says "process finished with exit code 0" (Using pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

Whenever I try to enter something into the prompt, it says "process finished with exit code 0" and doesn't activate my next line of code!

I'll use "---" to indicate where my code is that isn't activating (below the line):

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print(name, ", huh? That's a great name!")
answer2 = input("Alright, Let's get going. Are you ready for Level 1?")
if answer2 is 'Y':
    # ---
    print("Alright, let's do it then!")
    ...
```

Comment: This is because `is` doesn't compare stuff, while `==` does. You're using the wrong operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do :

```
a = 'Y'
b = 'Y'
a is B #>>> return False
```

`is` checks if two objects are the same object, it works with integers, but strings are always different objects.

You may want to do :

```
answer2 == 'Y'
```

(Code 0 is a good sign, no error detected, like syntax or NameError)